# Date Format in a SELECT filter query

Tags: c#, mysql, select, date-format

I have a field *Date* type. I'm recording data in the format *dd/mm/yyyy*.
It's displaying just fine. But when I try to use a filter in my *select query* it returns me every single row. I tried this:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE dt_start >=  '01/04/2007'
```

and

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE dt_start >=  DATE_FORMAT('01/04/2007', "%d/%m/%yyyy")
```

Now, if I try this, it works perfect:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE dt_start >=  '2007/04/01'
```

I know it's the standar *MySQL* date format on it's Site. But I'd like to know a way to achieve this goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you want to convert your dates is like this:

```
UPDATE [table name] SET [date field name] = STR_TO_DATE('01/04/2007', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

That will convert all of our dates to the standard like Gordon Linoff said. IF you want them to look like your dates originally when you pull them out, then you can use dateformat in your query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT([date field], '%m/%d/%Y') AS myDate FROM [table name]
```

Does that make sense?
I also agree with Gordon that it's easier to store your dates with the standard format. You can manipulate and compare dates more easily this way.

**EDIT**

```
SELECT * FROM [your table] WHERE date >= STR_TO_DATE('01/04/2007', '%m/%d/%Y')
```

With this, you don't have to change your date types and you can just change the string you want to evaluate against to a date in the where clause. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Ok, but It's recording in the format I wish, *dd/mm/yyyy*. When I execute a *select query* the returned date format is perfect aswell... The only problem I'm facing is when I try to filter the data from database with a different this format... ;s  I just found a way to change the format in the *codebehind*, guess I'll go with it ;s

Comment: Ok, I think I misunderstood your question. I updated my answer to use the STR_TO_DATE where you wanted it in the WHERE clause. @PlayHardGoPro

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the conversion between dates and strings when you do a comparison.  You can put the constant that you want as:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE dt_start >=  STR_TO_DATE('01/04/2007', '%d/%m/%yyyy')  ;
```

However, I would strongly recommend that you use the ISO standard date format in your queries.  This is YYYY-MM-DD.  You can output whatever format you like, but using the standard in your queries is a good idea.

Comment: your code: *FUNCTION DataBaseName.STR2DATE does not exist*

Comment: It's called `STR_TO_DATE`